# c++ using nested template classes for carrying type information

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

When i try to compile the following code in VS 2012 i get errors on the Consumer class's typedef lines starting with:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Is this a problem with the compiler or is the code no longer valid c++? (The project it is extracted from certainly used to build without problems on older versions of VS - and gcc iirc - but that was about 10 years ago!)

```
struct TypeProvider
{
  template<class T> struct Container
  { 
    typedef vector<T> type; 
  };
};

template<class Provider>
class Consumer 
{
  typedef typename Provider::Container<int>::type intContainer;
  typedef typename Provider::Container<double>::type doubleContainer;
};
```

There is a workaround for it but i just wonder if it should be required:

```
struct TypeProvider    
{
   template<typename T> struct Container { typedef vector<T> type; };
};

template<template<class T> class Container, class Obj>
struct Type
{
  typedef typename Container<Obj>::type type;
};

template<typename Provider>
class TypeConsumer
{
  typedef typename Type<Provider::Container, int>::type intContainer;
  typedef typename Type<Provider::Container, double>::type doubleContainer;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to help the compiler know that `Container` is a template:

```
template<class Provider>
class Consumer 
{
  typedef typename Provider:: template Container<int>::type intContainer;
  typedef typename Provider:: template Container<double>::type doubleContainer;
};
```

This is very well explained in the accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: thanks; c++ has changed since i last delved into it!

Comment: @ian.witz this particular aspect has been standard from the beginning. But MSVC hasn't always strictly implemented the standard when it comes to templates.

Comment: i don't think it was just msvc - the code i'm porting was part of a university project that was also built on solaris and linux - although not by me.